# Use completing-read to call arbitrary function

Tags: completion, completing-read

How can one pass a list of (arbitrary) functions to `completing-read` and run the selected candidate? Something like this:

```lisp
(defun find/buffer ()
  (interactive)
   (completing-read "Chose one: "
            '(("find-file" . 'find-file)("switch-to-buffer" . 'switch-to-buffer))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the quote in front of each function symbol. You've already quoted the alist.
2. Just look up the choice in the alist to get the function, then call it.

```lisp
(defun find/buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((choices  '(("find-file" . find-file)
                     ("switch-to-buffer" . switch-to-buffer)))
         (choice   (completing-read "Choose one: " choices)))
    (call-interactively (cdr (assoc choice choices)))))
```

But if you make no difference between the name to choose and the function-symbol name then you might as well just do this:

```lisp
(defun find/buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively
    (intern (completing-read "Choose one: " '(find-file switch-to-buffer)))))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.